# Asking whether it will take a long time to complete something

Tags: phrase-request

If I want to ask someone whether it will take a long time to complete something, can I ask

> Will it take long?

Does this sentence look awkward or is it the correct way to ask?

Comment: That's a perfectly acceptable and common question.  Good job!

Comment: Yes, you can ask like that. This is perfect...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  There are lots of ways you could ask, and that's one of them:

> - Will it take long?
> - Will it take a long time?
> - Will it take a long time to finish?
> - When do you think it'll be done?
> - When do you think it might be done?
> - Could you tell me when you think it might be done?
> - Do you have any idea how long it might take?

As usual, you can insert meaningless hedge words like *might* to soften the question, and you can make it more polite by using less direct language such as *could you* instead of *will*.  What level of politeness or directness is appropriate is, of course, something you'll have to determine by context.

And context can change everything.  For example, if you're dropping off a document to get copies printed up, you might ask when you can come back to pick them up.  The following question isn't *literally* about when the printing will finish or how long it will take, but it would nonetheless be a perfectly natural way of asking:

> - When should I come back?

But speaking devoid of context, your way is fine.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​